Kubernetes php-fpm & nginx slow to start
Im trying to put a php symfony project on kubernetes !
It work but my php-fpm is slow to start
I build this as one pod with one php container and one nginx container
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-deployment
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: php
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.php.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  minReadySeconds: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%    # Specifies the maximum number of Pods that can be unavailable during the update process (in percentage or number).
      maxSurge: 25%          # Specifies the maximum number of additional Pods that can be created above the desired number of Pods during the update process (in percentage or number).
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 15
      initContainers:
        - name: init-symfony
          image: {{ .Values.php.image }}  
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - |
              cp -R /var/www/symfony/. /var/www/share 
              cd /var/www/share
              php bin/console c:c || true
              chown www-data:www-data -R . 
          env:
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: 'postgresql://dummy:dummy@dummy:5432/dummy?serverVersion=14'
          volumeMounts:
            - name: www-storage
              mountPath: /var/www/share
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: {{ .Values.php.image }}
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - |
            php-fpm
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 15"]
        # resources:
        #   requests:
        #     memory: "1024Mi"
        #     cpu: "50m"
        #   limits:
        #     memory: "2048Mi"
        #     cpu: "100m"
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 9000
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 2
          failureThreshold: 3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: php-config-volume
          mountPath: /var/www/symfony/.env.local
          subPath: php.conf
        - name: www-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/symfony
        - name: key-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/symfony/config/jwt

      - name: nginx
        image: {{ .Values.php.image }} 
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "10m"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /nginx/heal
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 2
          failureThreshold: 3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/symfony      
      volumes:
        - name: php-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: php-config 
        - name: www-storage
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: key-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-key-claim

So with this chart when i restart or do a rolling update my first container wait the second to be ready (so php-fpm is running on port 9000 and nginx on 80)
On my nginx i created a /nginx/health to check when it is ready
I tried to run my pod without runing php-fpm and start it by hand with the command php-fpm (it write php-fpm is ready to handle connection) and it take a lot of time 'arround 30 seconds' to show my page
One of the solution that i get is to put the nginx readyness probe to smt high that fpm can start without terminating the old pod
but i wonder why php-fpm tell me that he is listening for request but is not fully ready
Thanks :D !

can you add php bin/console cache:warmup . This can reduce the time PHP-FPM takes to serve the first request. Increase Nginx Readiness Probe Interval and see

@Arko I can add it in my 'initContainers' the cache is based on files or system ? (so do i run it on the php or the initContainer wich copy files in my fpm and my nginx containers)

PHP-FPM's delayed readiness can be due to several factors, including the readiness probe configuration, resource allocation, or caching/warming up issues in Symfony.
Try increasing the initialDelaySeconds and periodSeconds values. Setting initialDelaySeconds to around 20–30 seconds could give PHP-FPM time to initialize fully before Kubernetes checks readiness.
Assuming your Dockerfile for PHP-FPM and NGINX for Symfony is ready and pushed

Configure your yamls accordingly
pvc
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: symfony-storage
  namespace: symfony
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi


deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: symfony-deployment
  namespace: symfony
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: symfony
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: symfony
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-fpm
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/symfony-php-fpm:latest
        command: ["php-fpm"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 9000
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 3
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "1024Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/www/symfony
            name: symfony-storage

      - name: nginx
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/symfony-nginx:latest
        command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /nginx/health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 3
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "10m"
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/www/symfony
            name: symfony-storage

      volumes:
      - name: symfony-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: symfony-storage



service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: symfony-service
  namespace: symfony
spec:
  selector:
    app: symfony
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer



checkout symfony dockerfile and build symfony on k8s

Hum i think i already tried the PVC and it was always empty ! thats why i used a volume with emptyDir

I added the cache warmup i change php socket to a sock file instead of port (so im using a volume to share it) but it still take 7 - 8 sec before responding even if i change the readyness probe on nginx

For your first comment- Using emptyDir will result in losing cached data on pod restarts. To persist cache and speed up pod starts, suggested PVC.
For your second comment- Since you have already added cache:warmup, tweaked the readiness probes, can you check If opcache is enabled? enabling it can significantly reduce loading time. See if you can use opcache https://www.hibit.dev/posts/175/boosting-php-performance-with-opcache#:~:text=OPCache%20is%20essential,for%20handling%20traffic. and https://loadforge.com/guides/maximizing-your-php-applications-speed-with-opcache-optimization

Ok i found something !
When i deploy and refresh my page right after there is 5 sec when i cannot accès my page. But if i wait 10mn an refresh its the same. So i think the first connection is always like this. php-fpm is initiating the first connection !

so there is probably a settings to counter this !

i added the cache clear and warmup in my docker entrypoint ! i wil try with a PVC if the problem is still here !

I found a solution ! With my first Deployement.
In the php container cmd i added before the php-fpm, a cache clear and a cache warmup and it fixed all my problems
